# Is it possible to export to a csv without the value being encapsulated as a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I want my CSV to look like this :

```
12345,John Smith,result1,result2,result3
```

But instead it becomes this :

```
12345,John Smith,"result1,result2,result3"
```

The trouble is I don't want the `"`'s in the the result.

The ruby code that produces this is this :

```
@a = MyObject.find(x)
CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << @a.id, @a.name, results.collect{|result| presentable(result) }.join(',')
```

If I do this action :

```
results.collect{|result| presentable(result) }.join(',')
```

It returns :

```
"result1,result2,result3"
```

But how can I have it *"not be a String"* so that it can be appended to my CSV without quotation marks `"` ?

Comment: If not a string, then what should they be?

Comment: The code you have posted should fail with a syntax error detected after `@a.id,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `.join(',')` you are concatenating the results into a single string. In other words, you are passing 3 elements to CSV rather than your desired 5.

You need to:

1. Remove the `join` and
2. Use the splat operator to break up the enumerator (from `collect`) into individual elements (otherwise you'll get an array inside an array).

Try this:

```
@a = MyObject.find(x)
CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << [@a.id, @a.name, *results.collect{ |result| presentable(result) }]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that your code would return `unexpected ',', expecting $end`, it looks like you want either to escape the `"` characters or use different column separator than `,`. I hope ;)

Iirc Ruby `CSV` class supports parameters like `:col_sep` and `:quote_char`, you should check them out.